# How can I add total row after some results?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I need to add the row Total after each month of my result, like:

```
Month   ID  Mod1    Mod2    Mod3
2014/1  1   5       4       2
2014/1  2   1       5       3
Total       6       9       5
2014/2  3   6       3       2
2014/2  4   2       1       4
Total       8       4       6
```

This is my query without the row Total:

```
SELECT
  id_user,
  month,
  year,
  SUM(IF(mod = 1, 1, 0)) AS mod_1,
  SUM(IF(mod = 2, 1, 0)) AS mod_2,
  SUM(IF(mod = 3, 1, 0)) AS mod_3
FROM
  DW_RM_Log
WHERE
  year = 2014
GROUP BY
  year, month, id_user
ORDER BY
  year, month
```

How can I do this in mySQL?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a GROUP BY query WITH ROLLUPS:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN id_user IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(`year`, '/', `Month`)
                                ELSE 'Total' END AS `Year_Month`,
  id_user,
  SUM(IF(`mod` = 1, 1, 0)) AS mod_1,
  SUM(IF(`mod` = 2, 1, 0)) AS mod_2,
  SUM(IF(`mod` = 3, 1, 0)) AS mod_3
FROM
  DW_RM_Log
WHERE
  `year` = 2014
GROUP BY
  `year`, `month`, id_user
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING `year` IS NOT NULL AND `month` IS NOT NULL
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e2225/2).